# Parent/Child Web Pages - Force Submit

Tags: javascript, submit, parent-child

I have a parent web page with a customer # and a name search.  If you manually enter a new customer #, you can submit it to save your data.  If I enter a value in the name search it launches a 2nd, pop-up page via javascript window.open and clears several inputs (to be re-populated in a moment).

```
    function displayLookupWindow() {
        // Launch the popup
        newWindow=window.open('../administration/ad_custlookup.asp?userid=<%=user_id%>&company_nbr='+document.mainForm.txtCompany.value+'&guid=<%=GUID%>&lookup='+document.mainForm.customer_lookup.value,'customerLookupWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=520,height=650');

        // Clear the values in the parent screen
        // This must come AFTER the window.open command
        // This will execute as the window.open is also executing!
        document.getElementById("txtCustomer").value = "";
        document.getElementById("customer_lookup").value = "";
        document.getElementById("txtCustName").value = "";

        newWindow.focus();
    }
```

The pop-up web page builds a list of customers containing the desired string from the parent page.  When the user clicks on the desired customer, that customer # is passed back to the parent web page and the popup web page closes:

```
    function SetName(CustNo) {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            // txtCustomer is the name of the id on the parent page.
            // This is how we pass the value back to the parent page.
            var txtCustomer = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtCustomer");
            txtCustomer.value = document.getElementById(CustNo).value;

            var txtCustChanged = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtCustChanged");
            txtCustChanged.value = "Y";
        }
        window.close();
    }
```

This cleanly populates the customer # input on the parent page with the desired value.

How do I then force it to SUBMIT the resulting customer number (as if they had manually typed in the value)?  onchange does not work because the user did not enter the change (it was populated by javascript).